# Hybrid App built for Android crashes on entering numbers into an input box

Tags: android, html, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm not sure if anyone has seen anything like this before (I hope you have!) but it's stumped me.

Basically, I have a **HTML 5 on Android** which has input boxes. Whenever I enter numbers into these boxes, the app crashes.

I have tried this with **input type="text"** and **type="number"** but it's no good, the same result occurs.

If I type a **0 then it will crash** on the next number entered. If I lead with something other than a 0 it will usually crash when I enter the fourth number.

This behaviour is really peculiar. If I enter text into an input box of type text it's absolutely fine. If I enter the numbers really quickly, it can't cope and crashes. If I enter them slowly, the app copes better and allows me to enter more numbers.

I'm building my app with Worklight and for a Samsung Galaxy S3. Everything else functions perfectly, but this is a pretty big problem as it stands.

Has anyone encountered this or can suggest a way around this? I'm using Dojo text boxes (although I have used standard html 5 input boxes as well and the same end result is reached). Dojo works fine everywhere else in the app.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: in  which device you r testing ?

Comment: Even i'm facing the similar crash, to be precise my app only crashes when numerical 7 is entered...It would be appreciated if someone answers this post.

Comment: Did either of you find a solution? I am also experiencing same issue testing an app I created in eclipse using both the android emulator and phone device, and found that any time I enter more than 7 sequential numbers in an input text box, the app immediately closes and the Eclipse LogCat dispalys: 01-14 20:52:12.888: A/libc(617): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000c (code=1), thread 631 (WebViewCoreThre) Example input is '1234567890', but, form and app closes when I get to number 9. However, if I enter alphabetical chars after the 8th charactaer (e.g., '12345678AB') it works fine.

Comment: So what did you do to solve this?  - or workaround it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, I upgraded to the latest version of Worklight (which is how I'm building my hybrid apps) and the problem was resolved. I should've checked before I upgraded, but I assume the version of PhoneGap that comes packaged with it was a later build (as that's where my problem was being created). I hope that helps you!